# How many solutions for $\cos(x)=1/\sqrt{2}$

Tags: trigonometry

I have been counting on this for the entire night and I can't get it right even if I watch a lot of Khan Academy and read online.

How many solutions has the equation $\cos(x)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ in the interval $\Big[\dfrac{\pi}{11}, 7\pi\Big]$

I will be extremely relieved once I finally know!

Comment: Can you find any solutions to the equation, in any interval?

Comment: Note that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$.

Comment: I believe it would be in pi/4 but I'm not at all sure

Comment: @IdiotNerd Yes!  But there are more solutions, right?  For two reasons (1) the cosine function is even, so $\cos(-\theta) = \cos(theta)$ for any $\theta$, and (2) the cosine function is $2\pi$-periodic, so $\cos(\theta + 2\pi) = \cos(\theta)$ for any $\theta$.  Can you see how to use this to get more solutions?

Comment: @XanderHenderson not completely... When I count I get it to four solutions but I don't think it's right :

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the equation, $x$ represents an angle which has cosine $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.  That is, $x$ is an angle that intersects the unit circle at a point with horizontal coordinate equal to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ (I am not going to call it the $x$-coordinate, because we are already using $x$ to represent an angle---this is what I would call bad pedagogy).  It is not too hard to see that there are two such angles:
$$ x = \frac{\pi}{4} \qquad\text{and}\qquad x = -\frac{\pi}{4}; $$
the angle $\pi/4$ intersects the unit circle at a point $\big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\big)$, and the angle $-\pi/4$ intersects at the point $\big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\big)$.

BUT!  We could go around the unit circle over and over and over again, and pick up new solutions each time.  Since each time around corresponds to adding (or subtracting) $2\pi$ radians, we get a new solution to the equation every time we add some integer multiple of $2\pi$ to any solution that we already have. 
 Therefore the set of solutions is the set
$$ \left\{ \pm\frac{\pi}{4} + 2k\pi : k\in\mathbb{Z} \right\}.$$

Now, we are looking for solutions between (and including) $\frac{\pi}{11}$ and $7\pi$.  There are slightly more elegant ways of approaching the problem, but for now, why don't we just brute force it?

We can start by noting that $-\frac{\pi}{4}$ is too small to be in the interval.  However, observe that
$$ \frac{\pi}{11} < \frac{\pi}{4} < 7\pi, $$
so that works.  Next, we can take our two solutions, and add $2\pi$ to them.  This gives us
$$ -\frac{\pi}{4} + 2\pi = \frac{7\pi}{4}
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\frac{\pi}{4} + 2\pi = \frac{9\pi}{4}.
$$
Both of these are greater than $\frac{\pi}{11}$, and by noting that $7\pi = \frac{28\pi}{4}$, we can see that both are less than $7\pi$.  Hence we have two more values that work.  Going around the circle again, we get solutions
$$ \frac{7\pi}{4} + 2\pi = \frac{15\pi}{4}
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\frac{9\pi}{4} + 2\pi = \frac{17\pi}{4}.
$$
Again, these solutions work.  So, go around again:
$$ \frac{15\pi}{4} + 2\pi = \frac{23\pi}{4}
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\frac{17\pi}{4} + 2\pi = \frac{25\pi}{4}.
$$
Yay!  More solutions!  Once more:
$$ \frac{23\pi}{4} + 2\pi = \frac{31\pi}{4}
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\frac{25\pi}{4} + 2\pi = \frac{33\pi}{4}.
$$
Ah.  Darn.  Both of these are too big.  And if we add more multiples of $2\pi$, we are just going to get bigger and bigger numbers.  Thus we have found all of the solutions between $\frac{\pi}{11}$ and $7\pi$.  Listing them out, they are
$$\frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{7\pi}{4}, \frac{9\pi}{4}, \frac{15\pi}{4}, \frac{17\pi}{4}, \frac{23\pi}{4}, \frac{25\pi}{4}.$$
Therefore I count 7 solutions in the desired interval.

---

In the [linked graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator), the interval of interest is shown in grey/black, the cosine is plotted in red, and the blue line is at $y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.  The points where the red and blue lines intersect are solutions to the equation
$$\cos(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}.$$
Counting the points of intersection confirms the above analysis (assuming that we trust the technology).

Comment: Wow, this explanation is som helpful! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I like the following way.

We obtain $$x=\frac{\pi}{4}+2\pi k$$ or
$$x=-\frac{\pi}{4}+2\pi k,$$
where $k\in\mathbb Z$.

Now, we have $$\frac{\pi}{11}\leq\frac{\pi}{4}+2\pi k\leq7\pi$$ or
$$-\frac{7}{88}\leq k\leq\frac{27}{8},$$ which gives
$$0\leq k\leq3$$ and $4$ values of $k$ or
$$\frac{\pi}{11}\leq-\frac{\pi}{4}+2\pi k\leq7\pi,$$ which is
$$\frac{15}{88}\leq k\leq\frac{29}{8}$$ and from here
$$1\leq k\leq3,$$ which gives more $3$ values and we got $7$ solutions.

Answer (score 0):

And one more attempt:

$\cos (x) =(1/2)√2$ has

$2$ solutions  $x_1 = π/4$ , $x_2 = 2π - π/4$ in the interval $[0,2π].$

Consider $[π/11,7π].$

Note: $π/11 \lt π/4$ , hence we count $2$ solutions for the first interval below.

Count : $[0,2π],[2π,4π],[4π,6π] $,  I.e $3× 2$ solutions in $[0,6π]$.

In the interval $[6π,7π]$ there is $1$ more solution.

Altogether: $7$ solutions  of

$\cos(x) = (1/2)√2$ in $[π/11,7π]$.